# How to config paypal credit card in YII framework

Tags: paypal, yii2, payment-gateway, yii-extensions

I working in paypal credit card configuration in YII framework But I`m struggling to config paypal credit card in **YII and Paypal version:53.0.**
**Errors: [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10752**

kindly provide me procedure for paypal credit card config in YII framework.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the error message you are receiving indicates. This comes from the PayPal Developer site:

> 10752     Gateway Decline     This transaction cannot be processed.   The transaction was declined by the issuing bank, not PayPal. The merchant should attempt another card.         DoDirectPayment

[PayPal API Error Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/)

That particular error message means that the credit card was declined. That is a valid response to a DoDirectPayment API Call.